# numpy select multiple ranges from a 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Let's say I have a 1D array of values:

```
T = np.array([1.3, 8.9, 1.4, 3.2, 4.4, 7.0, 2.0, 6.9]
```

and I have a list of start indices:

```
I = np.array([5, 2, 4, 1])
```

For each start index, I would like to grab `m` consecutive values from `T` starting at the start index. So, the final output for `m=3` should be a 2D array with:

```
T = np.array([[7.0, 2.0, 6.9],
              [1.4, 3.2, 4.4],
              [4.4, 7.0, 2.0],
              [8.9, 1.4, 3.2]])
```

I could simply loop through the indices but I was hoping that there were a more efficient approach:

```
m = 3
out = np.empty((len(I), m))
for j, i in enumerate(I):
    out[j] = T[j : j+m]
```

Comment: Use `s = T; l = m; i = I` with the linked Q&A's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that does not require installing additional dependencies:

```
def rolling_window(a, window):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

m = 3
rolling_T = rolling_window(T, m)  # Note that this is a very efficient view
out = rolling_T[I]
```